# Running `ls` with `--color=auto|always` needs execute permissions

Tags: permissions, ls, colors

I've been thoroughly confused for quite some time with `ls` just plain refusing to work in some places, even though I have read permissions. After messing around a bit, it turns out that `ls` works fine, as long as I run it with `--color=never`, but as soon as I use `auto` or `always`, I get the familiar `Permission denied` error on everything where I lack execution permissions.

What causes this and how can I stop it while keeping my `ls` output in color?

Update: Okay, finally figured it out (as usual, directly after asking for help). You need execute permissions to enter directories, so cd and ls --color doesn't work on directories without it. I have no idea why I can still ls --color=never on directories without it though. Curious why that is?

Comment: Are you trying to use `ls` on a directory which you do not have execution permission on it?

Comment: Plus give us examples, first, show the permission of what you are trying to use your `ls` command on, and then show us the output of your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the contents of a directory (the names of the entries) requires only read permission on the directory.

That means you can run `/bin/ls` and see all the names without a problem.

But to decide which color the names should be displayed with, `ls` uses other properties from the entries.  It uses metadata from the file (permissions, size, filetype, etc.)  This requires that it `stat()` the file, and that requires execute permission on the directory to succeed.

Just the names of the files in a directory: you only need read permission.
For metadata about the files in a directory: you need read and execute permission

Answer (score 2):

To just list the names of things in a directory, without caring about their types (etc.), just requires read permission on the directory.

In order to assign the color to the things inside a directory, `ls` needs to know stuff about them—type of entry (another directory, plain file, device, symlink, etc.), size, symlink target; it finds those by various syscalls on the entry. That requires the `+x` permission bit on the directory containing those items. (Actually, depending on the kernel version, you can still get some color—`getdents` can give both the name and type).

My version of `ls`, by the way, still lists the directory after spitting out the permission denied errors (though all of the colors). And if you want to see something else weird, try `-l`:

```
$ ls -l test 2>/dev/null 
total 0
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? badsymlink
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? empty
p????????? ? ? ? ?            ? fifo
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? goodsymlink
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? notempty
```